# Accessing Django test client in setUpClass

Tags: python, django, testing

I have a test class where I would like to create and login a user once:

```
class UserModelTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['group_perms']

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.standard_user = UserFactory(first_name='Firsto', last_name='Namo')

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.standard_user.delete()

    def setUp(self):
        self.moderator = ModeratorFactory() # I'm here because I need access to fixtures to work - but I'd rather be in setUpClass
        self.client.login(email=self.moderator.email, pass='pass') # I'm here because I need access to self.client to work - but I'd rather be in setUpClass
```

So my question (or two):

- Can I move the moderator into the `setUpClass` method (given it needs
  access to fixtures)?
- Can I access `self.client` in `setUpClass`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer is no - but that's not the end of the story.

`self.client` is a convenience that is configured as part of the "pre-test" sequence. This means it is configured on a per-test basis; so you can use it in `setUp()`, but not `setUpClass()`. Similarly for fixtures - they're set up as part of pre-test, so they're not available in `setUpClass()`.

However, there's nothing especially magical about `self.client` - it's just an instance of `django.test.Client` that Django sets up for you because it's something that is very useful to have around. You can set up your own client if you want - you just have to instantiate an instance of `Client`:

```
from django.test import Client
...
self.myclient = Client()
```

and then use `self.myclient` as you would `self.client`. This can be very useful if you need to check "two user" behaviour - for example, checking that if an admin approves an article, a user can then see it. You create two clients, log them in with separate accounts, and then `GET` the same article URL with each client. In your case, you could create a client purely for class setup activities.

The only caveat on using `django.test.Client` in `setUpClass()` relate to transactional side effects. `setUpClass()` doesn't fall inside the transaction protection of a test case, so anything you do in `setUpClass()` will be "permanent" on the test database. You'll need to manually roll back or undo any database changes that `setUpClass()` makes, or you'll get cross-testcase side effects.

If you're using Django 1.8, you can use `setUpTestData()` instead - in this case, anything the client does *would* be protected by a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to move the creation of the moderator into the `setUpClass` method in Django 1.7.

Django 1.8 has a [`setUpTestData`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) hook that you will be able to use.

```
class UserModelTest(TestCase):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.moderator = ModeratorFactory()
```

Comment: Looking at the docs `setUpTestData` appears to be a class method, so I assume I will have the same problem.

Comment: The fact that it's a class method shouldn't be a problem. I've fixed my example above so that it is a class method.

Comment: This seems correct, though I am not yet running 1.8, so I won't mark is as correct... yet :P FYI: using the setUpClass method does not work as expected - it actually runs once per test.  See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/N0HEAD1ht8k

Comment: I don't think the thread you've linked says that it `setUpClass` runs once per test, it says that the changes in `setUpClass` are not rolled back between test case classes. That behaviour is fixed in Django 1.8 by [ticket 20392](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20392), the same ticket that adds the `setUpTestData` method.